# Adobe Illustrator - Automate changing TrueType fonts to OpenType versions

Tags: javascript, css, applescript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to figure out a script (be it javascript or AppleScript) or anything that can change truetype fonts in multiple .eps files to the opentype (otf) versions of those fonts without having to do it in Illustrator manually for each file.

This is probably impossible or but any suggestions even if they don't do this exactly would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the following AppleScript, however you'll need to define a list of font mappings.

#### 1. Example AppleScript

```cs
set fontMap to {{"Courier", "CourierPSStd"}, {"Baskerville", "BaskervilleMTStd-Regular"}, {"GillSans", "GillSansStd"}}

tell application "Finder"
  set chosenFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder which contains the EPS files to process"
  set epsFileList to files of entire contents of folder chosenFolder whose name extension is "eps" and creator type is "ART5" as list
  my replaceFonts(epsFileList, fontMap)
end tell

on replaceFonts(epsFileList, fontMap)
  tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    repeat with thisEpsFile in epsFileList
      set user interaction level to never interact
      open thisEpsFile as alias without dialogs
      tell document 1
        repeat with thisMap in fontMap
          try
            set text font of (characters of stories whose properties contains {text font:text font (item 1 of thisMap)}) to text font (item 2 of thisMap) of application "Adobe Illustrator"
          end try
        end repeat
        close saving yes
      end tell
      set user interaction level to interact with all
    end repeat
  end tell
end replaceFonts
```

---

#### 2. What does the script do?

1. It prompts the user to select a folder which contains the `.eps` files to be batch processed.
2. Each `.eps` file found in the chosen folder (including those in subfolders) are opened in Illustrator repeatedly.
3. Upon opening each file it finds all instances of a given font and replaces it with another given font.
4. Each file is saved, then closed before processing the next file.

---

#### 3. What you'll need to do before running the script...

Unfortunately, there is no way for Illustrator to know which *TrueType* font should be replaced with which equivalent *OpenType* font. So you'll need to define which font should be mapped/replaced with which font yourself. To do this you'll need to define each font paring in the first line of code which currently reads:

```cs
set fontMap to {{"Courier", "CourierPSStd"}, {"Baskerville", "BaskervilleMTStd-Regular"}, {"GillSans", "GillSansStd"}}
```

This line of code, (a two dimensional Array), given it's current values informs the script to:

- Replace any instances of `"Courier"` with `"CourierPSStd"`.
- Replace any instances of `"Baskerville"` with `"BaskervilleMTStd-Regular"`.
- Replace any instances of `"GillSans"` with `"GillSansStd"`.

**Tip: How can I find the correct names of fonts to create the `fontMap` array?**

I suggest you launch Illustrator and run this very simple script from the *AppleScript Editor*:

```cs
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
  set fontNames to name of every text font
end tell
```

If you look in the *Result* panel in the *AppleScript Editor* you'll see a list of names for each font available on your computer.

---

#### 4. Notes

The line of code on line 5 which reads;

```cs
set epsFileList to files of entire contents of folder chosenFolder whose name extension is "eps" and creator type is "ART5" as list
```

obtains the list of `.eps` files to process from the chosen folder. Currently any file found which has a `name extension` of `"eps"`and a `creator type` of `"ART5"`, (`"ART5"` means it's created by Illustrator), will be included in the batch process. You may need to omit the part which reads:

```cs
and creator type is "ART5"
```

if your `.eps` files have not been created by Illustrator. However, the script may then attempt to process any bitmap `.eps` files too - (such as those created in PhotoShop).

---

**Caution:** *This script currently saves any changes made to your files, so it can be quite destructive if you haven't defined the appropriate `fontMap` array. I recommend that that you run this on duplicates of your `.eps` files whilst testing and maybe omit the line of code which reads `close saving yes` until you're confident your `fontMap` is yielding the desired results*